# Buffer overflow causes extra characters to be executed by terminal as shell command

Tags: c, security, io, limit, buffer-overflow

I'm getting myself initiated to *buffer overflow* risks, especially when it comes to low-level C library input/output functions and trying to understand how it relates to *memory exploitation* and *code injection*.

I am considering the following chunk of code and the weird behavior its execution gives :

```
int main ()
{
     char buffer[10];

     int r = read (STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 14);
     puts(buffer);

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now when given the following 17-size input

`Hello, World !pwd`

I get the following output :

```
Hello, Wor
> pwd
/media/...<current working directory path>
```

As shown by the output, the 3 extra characters (here intentionally `pwd` for demonstration purposes) - that were out of bounds for the specified limit of the `read` function - got taken over by the terminal and executed as a shell command.

What causes this behavior, from a *low-level* perspective ?
Can that be used to carry out a *code injection* ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site, and this is much to broad (please see ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)). Find a good book or tutorial site.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude A great deal of very similar questions have been asked and answered on Stack Overflow, even broader and more technical than this one.

Comment: Why is that weird behaviour? Your code reads in 14 bytes, leaving the rest for the shell to read and process

Comment: @programmersn, Some programmer dude gave you links to the SO documentation describing what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  Whether those criteria have always been the same or have always been strictly followed is immaterial.  Whether it *applies* to your question is a separate issue.

Comment: Agreed, @ChrisTurner.  The surprising thing here is the manifestation of the actual UB: that the output of the `puts` is truncated relative to the input that apparently was consumed.  That the shell reads and processes the remaining input is normal.

Comment: @JohnBollinger What does UB stand for ?

Comment: UB stands for *undefined behavior*.  In this case, you get undefined behavior by overrunning the bounds of your array (supposing that the `read` really does read the full 14 bytes, which appears to be the case, but is not guaranteed).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I imagine it's due to `r` being declared after `buffer` and set to 14

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've reworded the question, please consider lifting the hold on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As shown by the output, the 3 extra characters (here intentionally `pwd`
>   for demonstration purposes) - that were out of bounds for the
>   specified limit of the `read` function - got taken over by the terminal
>   and executed as a shell command.
>
> How is that possible, from a *low-level* perspective ?

As @ChrisTurner observed first in comments, there is nothing surprising about the `pwd` being interpreted as input to the shell from which you launched the program, after the program exits.  Although each program has its own handle on it, they are reading from the same file, probably connected to a terminal.

Your program helps, though, by using a low-level I/O function, `read`, which will not consume any more bytes from that file than you request.  Contrast stream-based functions such as `fread`, `fgets`, and `scanf`, which most often perform *buffered* reads (this is a characteristic of the stream they operate upon, not the functions themselves).  In your particular case, any of these would consume all the input up to and including the first newline.

You do have a potential buffer overflow in your program, but it is a red herring.  The behavior you describe does depend on `read` reading the full 14 bytes requested, which it is not guaranteed to do, but which for all intents and purposes you can rely upon it to do when the standard input is connected to a terminal.  It having done so, your program will indeed exhibit undefined behavior, but the manifestation of that UB is likely to be constrained to the program's output (notice how it's truncated?) or even to be invisible to you.  It is not responsible for "pwd" being read as input by the parent shell.

> What about
>   non-console program execution, like *GUI apps*, *web apps*, and so on ...
>   How would they behave in this case ? And most importantly, what
>   security issues does this situation raise, in terms of *binary
>   exploitation and code injection*, and maybe other security aspects that
>   I'm not aware of ?

Only a person or program that has direct access anyway to the program's parent shell, if any, or to that shell's controlling terminal can feed input to it.  You have not demonstrated otherwise.  There is no particular security consideration to discuss.

Comment: Thanx for the detailed answer. So it has little to do with *code injection* or *memory exploitation*, if I understand well ?

Comment: @programmersn, the result that the shell reads and executes the "pwd" at the end of the input intended for your program has *nothing* to do with code injection or memory exploitation.